# Is it necesary to introduce noise in building fully homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is it necesary to introduce noise in building fully homomorphic encryption?

At present, almost all formally published FHE schemes are based on noisy approach. However, there are some noise-free FHE constructions posted at ePrint or arXiv. But all these noise-free FHE schemes have not been formally published, due to --- partially --- lack of provable security reductions. Gentry also published his position paper "Computing on the edge of chaos: Structure and randomness in encrypted computation" in ECCC. These progress urges me to think the above question.

Comment: All known FHE are based on *noisy* Somewhat HE.

Comment: Nuida's FHE framework is noise-free, although at present there is no provable secure instantiations. But lacking of successful noise-free constructions of FHE cannot stop us efforts in probing this problem.

Comment: A more suttble problem: What is the difference between noise and randomness? Say, we never think that Elgamal scheme and Pailler scheme are noise-based construction, although there are randomness involved in the encryption.

Comment: good point, didn't know that paper of  Nuida. Also, it seems that, is not clear what kind of finite non-commutative groups to use.  Noise in LWE based cryptosystems, is not random but follows gaussian distribution with small s.